# Careers 2.0 distance slider does not work on Chrome/Firefox

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

The Careers 2.0 distance slider does not work on Chrome or Firefox on Windows 8 Profesional:

[image: slider]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, looking at your image there, you didn't enter anything in the **where** box above. Hovering over the disabled slider will also tell you to enter a location. If it doesn't know where you're looking for jobs, it's a little hard to find jobs within a distance of it.